# Specifying where to plot object in grid

Tags: r

Lets say I specify a plot screen:

```
par(mfrow=c(3,3))
```

Now I would like to plot something but I would like to plot it in the (3,2) grid.

How can I  do this?

```
for (i in c(100,1000,10000)){
a<-runif(i)
plot.new()
plot(a)
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Plots are filled in the grid in order (rows first).  Each time you create a new plot with the `plot()` function, the plot is created in the next part of the grid.  If the entire grid is filled, a new blank plot grid is created and the plot is put in the first grid.  To skip a grid, you can use `plot.new()` or `frame()`, which is an alias for `plot.new()` to advance to the next part of the grid.

Comment: `lines()` places the lines on the current plot window (grid).  I edited my answer to be more clear.

Comment: the grid is 3x3, plot.new() places it in a weird order. do you know why?

Comment: Can you edit your question with the code you are running?  Then I can tell you why.

Comment: ok I've edited it with code. but this is just an example, so please don't offer a simpler solution for doing what the code does :)

Comment: Using the `plot()` function automatically calls `plot.new()` so you don't need it.  Sorry, I wasn't clear in my original answer.